# How do I reauthenticate my app?

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric, twitterkit

So, I'm building my app using the Twitter fabric framework and I have a Twitter Login Button. I compile my app and chose to run the app on my iPhone from Xcode. it asked to allow to allow access to Twitter system accounts and I mistakenly clicked "No". Now it refuses to compile as usual and gives this message:

```
[TwitterKit] did encounter error with message "Unable to authenticate using enter code herethe system account.": Error Domain=TWTRLogInErrorDomain Code=2 "User allowed permission to system accounts but there were none set up."
```

Can anyone advise on how to reauthenticate?